# Fluentlenium crashes on jquery in play framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fluentlenium

I want to write Fluentlenium tests but it crashes on jQuery. I use the standard integration into the play framework. I try to get the simple standard example to work. If I run test, get (most importantly)

```
    Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://cg.ch:3333/vassets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js#2)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://cg.ch:3333/vassets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js#2)
```

Im using jQuery v2.1.3.

Any ideas?

This is the full trace:

```
[error] Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver, took 6.175 sec
[error]     at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:484)
[error]     at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:463)
[error]     at org.fluentlenium.core.Fluent.goTo(Fluent.java:336)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$1.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:22)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$1.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:20)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:555)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:541)
[error]     at IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:20)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://cg.ch:3333/vassets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js#2)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1062)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
[error]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
[error]     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
[error]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:376)
[error]     at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:474)
[error]     ... 41 more
[error] Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://cg.ch:3333/vassets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js#2)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3688)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
[error]     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
[error]     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
[error]     ... 70 more
[error] Failed: Total 2, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 1
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     IntegrationTest
[error] (root/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed Mar 5, 2015 11:17:06 AM
```

Comment: Did you find a better resolution?

Answer (score 3):

The error happens because the play.test.Helpers.HTMLUNIT test browser has JavaScript enabled and is finding errors in the jQuery script source. The only workaround I've found is to disable JavaScript on the test driver.

So instead of invoking your test like

```
running(testServer(3333,fake), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
    public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) throws JAXBException, IOException {
```

You should do

```
running(testServer(3333,fake), new HtmlUnitDriver(), new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
    public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) throws JAXBException, IOException {
```

Of course, note that if you do this you should not expect the JavaScript code in your page to be executed inside the test browser.