# Disabling HtmlUnit javascript error in play framework integration test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, htmlunit

HtmlUnit is causing an integration test to fail because of a javascript issue in jquery. I am trying to figure out how to disable javascript checking in this context. I know there is client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) option, but don't know how to get to that in this context.  Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
            assertTrue(browser.pageSource().contains("Sears Home Services Platform Admin"));
        }
    });
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[error] - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':checked' error: Invalid selector: *:checked).] sourceName=[http://localhost:3333/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

Comment: HtmlUnit is not directly used. What is the framework used on top? Probably the answer lies there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question [Fluentlenium crashes on jquery in play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875492/fluentlenium-crashes-on-jquery-in-play-framework) suggests to replace `HTMLUNIT` by `new HtmlUnitDriver()`

This solved it for me.

your code would look something like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), new HtmlUnitDriver(), new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
            assertTrue(browser.pageSource().contains("Sears Home Services Platform Admin"));
        }
    });
}
```

According to him, this would disable javascript completely in your tests, as HTMLUNIT includes javascript and is finding errors in the jQuery source.

Answer (score 0):

Try these below

```
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.WindowProxy").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: I tried using this snippet in the BeforeAll() function of the test that uses TestBrowser / WithBrowser, but the StrictErrorReporter errors remained.
Using play framework 2.4 with Scala.  Changing jquery versions did not get rid of the errors either.  Any suggestions?